# Terraform - Module directory does not exist or cannot be read

Tags: terraform

I am trying to access **pubsubTopicCreationModule** from **dev_main.tf**. However, terraform is throwing following error

> Error: Unreadable module directory Unable to evaluate directory
> symlink: lstat ../../modules: no such file or directory Error: Failed
> to read module directory Module directory  does not exist or cannot be
> read

In dev-main.tf I am calling the module as follows

```
module "pub_sub_topic_creation" {
  count  = length(var.pub_sub_topic_names)
  source = "../../modules/pubsubTopicCreation"
  name   = element(var.pub_sub_topic_names, count.index)
}
```

I tried many combination of path including the path from root and each time I am getting similar error.

Can someone would please let me know what would be the correct path to source? following is my directory structure

[image]

Comment: I believe your directory structure indicates that you should use `source = "../../../modules/pubsubTopicCreation"`. There are some doc here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#modules-in-package-sub-directories

Comment: @Roar S. Thank you, but this is also not working and same error.

Comment: In which folder are you executing `terraform apply`?

Comment: its in mainProject/flows/workflows, and the Root project is mainProject/Root. The dev-main.tf file is in mainProject/Root/terraform/environments/dev

Comment: I believe @Marcin is on the right track. However, I came across this suggestion `source = "./pubsubTopicCreation"` here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23333#issuecomment-1247333818

Comment: I dont know if this helps but the error (symlink) is like "Unable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat modules: no such file or directory"

Comment: Tried this as well source = "./pubsubTopicCreation" and its still failing.

Comment: Last resort: `terraform -chdir=environments/dev apply`

Comment: Okay I will let you know when I try this.

Comment: What you showed, does not have any folders `mainProject/flows/workflows`.